# What are good strategies to transfer an audio over web https?

Tags: file-upload, mp3, audio-streaming, multipartform-data, flac

My andriod app is bandwidh constraint. It should work in as low as 64kbps net.

The user will record voice (max length 120 sec, avrage 60 sec)

and then will encode it with encoder (options are:

```
1. Losless: FLAC or ALAC?
2. lossy: MP3?
```

Say file is 1024 kb i.e. 1 MB.

```
So I am thinking sending file by dividing into of chunks of size 32kb 
and 
if response is received in 1 sec after request:
     exponentially increasing size of chunks then 
else  
    The app will binary search for exact chunk size.

3. Is my approach to transfer an audio from android to server 
feasible for low speed connections?
4. Or is it better to push the entire file in 
multi-part form-data to server in one https post call?
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing this:

1. Record an audio file
2. Compress file
3. Upload file

You are uploading over https which uses tcp.  There is no reason to exponentially increase the size of chunk because internally TCP does this automatically to fairly share bandwidth.  It is called Slow Start.
No reason to chunk up in to pieces and let it grow.  Additionally, the max packet size is 64k.

Just open a stream and send it.  Let the underlying network protocols take care of the details.
On your server, you probably have to change server settings to allow large file uploads and increase the timeout settings.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "open a stream and send it" ? Is it the same as normal https post call if using okhttp client?

Comment: You should be able use a an http or https web service and upload your file.  As for using http or https - That is determined by the url in your client code to connect to the server.